# winston killing node process

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I added winston logger to my node.js code which used to run until killed.
After adding logger, the process dies. Even if I simply require the logger and not use it.

My logger.js is:

```
var winston     = require ('winston'),
    path        = require ('path');
var DailyRotateFile = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new DailyRotateFile({
            name: 'dropped-key',
            datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH',
            filename: path.join(__dirname, "droppedKeyLog", "log_file.log"),
            level: 'silly'
        }),
        new DailyRotateFile({
            name: 'errorLogger',
            datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH',
            filename: path.join(__dirname, "errorLog", "log_file.log"),
            level: 'error'
        }),
        new DailyRotateFile({
            name: 'debug-file',
            datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH',
            filename: path.join(__dirname, "debugLog", "log_file.log"),
            level: 'debug'
        }),
        new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: 'debug' })

    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [
        new DailyRotateFile({
            name: 'exception-file',
            filename:  path.join(__dirname, "exceptionLog", "log_file.log"),
            datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH'
        })
    ]
});

logger.exitOnError = false;

module.exports = {
    debugLogger : logger.loggers.get('debugLogger'),
    keyLogger : logger.loggers.get('dropped-key')
};
```

I need to know why is this happening and how can I fix this.

Comment: You have not forgotten to include a module `winston` at `logger.js`?

Comment: I have included the module.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming after doing `npm install winston-daily-rotate-file --save`

```
var DailyRotateFile = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
```

in

```
module.exports = {
    debugLogger : logger.loggers.get('debugLogger'),
    keyLogger : logger.loggers.get('dropped-key')
};
```

You have written the name of debug logger transport module incorrect . It will be `debug-file`.

Also you have fetched those from logger.loggers. It will be from logger.transports.

Accordingly code will be :

```
module.exports = {
  debugLogger : logger.transports['debug-file'],
  keyLogger : logger.transports['dropped-key']
};
```

Your node is stuck in the module.exports part. Replace this and it will be running...

Comment: Thanks. It's not dying now but it still is not creating log files.
I'm calling this like `debugLogger.debug(func.name, ": input Data: ", data);`

Comment: You need to globalize the logger variable by removing the `var` . Use logger variable in whole project and set the level. e.g. logger.silly("Silly"); or logger.error("Error").

Comment: Or you can also use
log_obj = module.exports = {
  debugLogger : logger.transports['debug-file'],
  keyLogger : logger.transports['dropped-key']
};

and use it like

log_obj.debugLogger.debug(func.name, ": input Data: ", data);

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple transports in separate loggers/files you can use *categories*.

Check https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#working-with-multiple-loggers-in-winston

```
winston.loggers.add('cat-dropped',{
  transports:[
    new DailyRotateFile({
      name: 'dropped-key',
      datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH',
      filename: path.join(__dirname, "droppedKeyLog", "log_file.log"),
      level: 'silly'
    })
  ]
});

winston.loggers.add('cat-debug',{
  transports:[
   new DailyRotateFile({
        name: 'debug-file',
        datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH',
        filename: path.join(__dirname, "debugLog", "log_file.log"),
        level: 'debug'
    })
  ]
});

winston.handleExceptions(
  new DailyRotateFile({
    name: 'exception-file',
    filename:  path.join(__dirname, "exceptionLog", "log_file.log"),
    datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH'
}));
```

After that you can get the loggers.

```
var droppedLogger = winston.loggers.get('cat-dropped');
var debugLogger = winston.loggers.get('cat-debug');

droppedLogger.info('');
debugLogger.debug('');
```

If still not creating log files, check the path of filename, the folder log should be already created